# About Coleman's proof of the nonexistence of Goldstones in 1+1 dimensions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, symmetry-breaking

In his famous paper "There are no Goldstone Bosons in Two
Dimensions", this link http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103859034,
first he states that the $\delta(k^2)$ is not a distribution in two
dimension, and the Lemma (after Eq(10)) does not apply to $\delta(k^2)$ (in the
bracket at the end of the Lemma). And in Eq. (11a), the definition of
$F$ is just the Fourier  transform of (6), which means $F(k)= A
\delta(k^2)\theta(k^0)$, where $A$ is an irrelavent constant. Thus
$F(k)$ is not a well-defined distribution and the Lemma can not be
directly used on it. But before Eq. (18), he states " By the
lemma and the assumed support properties of $g$, the first integral (of
Eq. (15)) vanishes as $\lambda$ goes to infinity. " Eq.(15) is 
\begin{eqnarray}
[\int d^2k F(k) |\tilde h(k)|^2][\int d^2k F_{00}(k) |\tilde
h(k)|^2]\ge|[\int d^2k F_0(k) |\tilde h(k)|^2]|^2
\end{eqnarray}
and $\tilde h$ is defined in (16)
\begin{eqnarray}
\tilde h(k)= f(\lambda k_-)g(k_+)+f(\lambda k_+)g(k_-)
\end{eqnarray}
and the support of $g(x)$ does not include zero, $f(k)$ being a peaked
test function defined around Eq(8).
As $\lambda\to \infty$, the support of the two terms in $\tilde h(k)$
does not overlap and the first integral in (15) becomes
\begin{eqnarray}
\int d^2k F(k) (|f(\lambda k_-)g(k_+)|^2+|f(\lambda k_+)g(k_-)|^2)
\end{eqnarray}
It seems that Coleman's statement means that from the Lemma, $\lim_{\lambda\to \infty}\int dk_-
F(k)|f(\lambda k_-)|^2\sim \delta(k_+)$ and since $g(k_+=0)=0$ and
similar to the second term, the
integral vanishes. 
Since as I stated above $F(k)\sim \delta (k^2)$ and the Lemma can not
be used on it, how can he reach this result? 
And then he stated that since "$F_{00}$ is a positive distribution, and
the second integral is monotonic decreasing". It seems to me that since
$F_{00}$ is a well-defined distribution, the Lemma could be used on
it, and thus the second integral on the left of Eq.(15) is vanishing. 
It seems that Coleman's statement about $F_{00}$ integral just applies
to the $F$ integral, and the one for $F$ can be used on $F_{00}$.

Is this a typo of Coleman or a misunderstanding of mine?

Comment: If this report of mine is of any help : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Bf6yBv-SFITEdsbFZyMmgxcTQ/view?usp=sharing  Also https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/4876704.pdf has an easier way to arrive at your main result.